# Scikit Learn PolynomialFeatures - what is the use of the include_bias option?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, data-science, polynomials

In scikit-learn's PolynomialFeatures preprocessor, there is an option to include_bias. This essentially just adds a column of ones to the dataframe. I was wondering what the point of having this was. Of course, you can set it to False. But theoretically how does having or not having a column of ones along with the Polynomial Features generated affect Regression.

This is the explanation in the documentation, but I can't seem to get anything useful out of it relation to why it should be used or not.

> **include_bias : boolean**
>
> If True (default), then include a bias column, the feature in which
>   all polynomial powers are zero (i.e. a column of ones - acts as an
>   intercept term in a linear model).

Answer (score 21):

Suppose you want to perform the following regression:

```
y ~ a + b x + c x^2
```

where `x` is a generic sample. The best coefficients `a,b,c` are computed via simple matricial calculus. First, let us denote with `X = [1 | X | X^2]` a matrix with N rows, where N is the number of samples. The first column is a column of 1s, the second column is a column of values `x_i`, for all the samples i, the third column is a column of values `x_i^2`, for all samples i. Let us denote with B the following column vector `B=[a b c]^T` If Y is a column vector of the N target values for all samples i, we can write the regression as

```
y ~ X B
```

The `i`-th row of this equation is `y_i ~ [1 x_i x^2] [a b c]^t = a + b x_i + c x_i^2`.

The goal of training a regression is to find `B=[a b c]` such that `X B` be as close as possible to `y`.

If you don't add a column of `1`, you are assuming a-priori that `a=0`, which might not be correct.

In practice, when you write Python code, and you use `PolynomialFeatures` together with `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`, the latter takes care by default of adding a column of 1s (since in `LinearRegression` the `fit_intercept` parameter is `True` by default), so you don't need to add it as well in `PolynomialFeatures`. Therefore, in `PolynomialFeatures` one usually keeps `include_bias=False`.

The situation is different if you use `statsmodels.OLS` instead of `LinearRegression`

Comment: Thanks, the last part of your answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just like Anup, I liked how you included the last two paragraphs to clear up any confusion.

Comment: So here's a follow up. I am trying to fit a Lasso model. Now it internally has fit_intercept option as True, but PolynomialFeature also gives option to inclue_bias. 

Now using either of the ways to include bias/intercept term, the final outcome that I am getting is giving different values of intercept. Now if both do same thing, why is the intercept coming different?