# Explain why Lasso regression intercept coming different when we include intercept in data vs model fitting intercept by itself?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, lasso-regression

So I am trying to fit a Lasso Regression model with Polynomial Features.

To create these Polynomial Features, I am using `from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures`

It has a parameter inclue_bias which can be set to True or False as `PolynomialFeatures(degree=5, include_bias=False)`. This bias is nothing but the column of 1 that represents the intercept in the final equation. As explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60253780/2126357) in another answer.

The issue is arising, when I either set `include_bias=True` and then fit Lasso regression without an intercept as it has already been taken care of or I choose to not include bias and set `fit_intercept=True` in from `sklearn.linear_model import Lasso`. They technically should give result for the intercept coefficient right? But turns out they aren't coming out to be same.

Is there internally some bug in scikit learn or what am I missing here? Let me know if anyone wants to try this on their own with some data. I'll share some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `PolynomialFeatures.include_bias=True` but `Lasso.fit_intercept=False`, the lasso model thinks the all-ones column is just another feature, and so the "intercept term" is penalized with the L1 penalty.  When `PolynomialFeatures.include_bias=False` and `Lasso.fit_intercept=True`, the lasso model knows not to penalize the intercept that it is fitting.

Comment: Can I make Lasso to penalize intercept term too? I don't see any option for this actually.